# Why does booting Windows 7 take longer after adding a user account

Tags: boot, domain

I am using my laptop for school, aswell as for work. In order to access certain network drives at work, i need to be part of a domain. Therefore, when im at work i login to the domain there. Ever since i've added this domain, booting into my normal user account takes considerably longer. Why is this? I used to be very content with the booting speed improvements switching to a ssd resulted in, but now this gain is completely nullified.

Comment: Do you really need to be *part of* a domain? Just authenticating might be enough...

Comment: By "booting into my normal user account" do you mean it takes a long time to get to the desktop after logging on as a local (non-domain) user account?

Comment: No, the 'Please wait...' stage takes way longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user profile could be in roaming. This means that your user files are downloaded from server during login.